# windowSoftInputMode to display adjusted to window on phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap application in which two different windows need a different behaviour.

One is static and I don't want the keyboard to stretch the items, and the other is something like a terminal with a bottom input box in which I want it to display above the keyboard.

I have tried several combinations but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. How is it possible to be done?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oFzl.png)

On the view above the behaviour must be overlapping the Menu and on the view below the behaviour must be having the input box always visible when the keyboard is open.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B55Tq.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to use this below property in your android manifest file :

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"

Comment: and make sure that you set the theme property for activities. @android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar

Comment: @elvisrusu Thanks in advance. I've tried your solution but couldn't get it to work as expected. I updated the question with images that better explain the situation. Please consider them if you please.